# Rails 3 Dynamic Select List

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm wondering if anyone can provide an tips for getting a dynamic select list based on the value of another select list.  I've been trying with little success using a few different methods.  I've tried using the old observe_field method with the prototype_legacy_helpers, but was not able to get that working, and also the method outlined  at http://pullmonkey.com/2008/03/30/dynamic-select-boxes-ruby-on-rails/ (ended up with an undefined method 'map' for :id:Symbol when rendering the partial that defined the collection_select).  Any help would be appreciated.  I don't care how I get it working, just that it works.

Answer (score 0):

have you viewed the [RailsCast #88](http://railscasts.com/episodes/88-dynamic-select-menus) by Ryan Bates? This probably clear some things up :)

Comment: I have not yet.  Is it just me or has RailsCast been disappearing from my Google searches?  Recently I had trouble digging up old links which I had found useful.

Comment: I tried the cast.. it seems to leave bits out.. and as with most things.. it's those bit that make it all work.

Comment: That railscast is 5 years old, is it the best way to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do something like this..

```
$("#list1").change(function(){
    if ($(this).val()=="something")
        $("#list2").show()
    else
        $("#list3").show()
});
```

If you are wanting to manipulate one list, this might be helpful:

http://www.texotela.co.uk/code/jquery/select/